# Как должен выглядеть фолдер проекта React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть такая папка, где я пишу код на React. У меня такой вопрос: нужно ли каждому проекту React иметь в своём фолдере все эти папки или надо только public и src? Просто папка node_modules занимает немало место, и если в каждом проекте React иметь эту папку, то место может закончится... Я новичок в React, поэтому не ругайте, если что-то не пойму или неправильно скажу :)

Comment: Эта папка(node_modules) действительно занимает много места, это все установленные модули проекта, и эта директория не является частью проекта. Этого никак не избежать, но есть такие проекты как pnpm и yarn2 которые вроде как решают проблему используя общую директорию node_modules, но с их использованием могут возникать проблемы. Если вы отправляете проект например на github то папка node_modules не должна быть перемещена, так как всегда может быть сгенерирована снова `npm install`

Comment: Спасибо. Понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать один `node_modules` для нескольких проектов.

Из [**документации**](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a native module, and
> does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then node starts at the
> parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and
> attempts to load the module from that location.
>
> If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and
> so on, until the root of the file system is reached.
>
> For example, if the file at '/home/ry/projects/foo.js' called
> require('bar.js'), then node would look in the following locations, in
> this order:
>
> /home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js /home/ry/node_modules/bar.js
> /home/node_modules/bar.js /node_modules/bar.js

Так что просто поместите папку `node_modules` в каталог ваших проектов и добавьте любые модули, которые вы хотите. Когда `node` не находит каталог `node_modules` в папке вашего проекта, он автоматически проверяет родительскую папку. Сделайте свою структуру каталогов такой:

```
-projectName
--node_modules
--myproject1
---sub-project
--myproject2
```

Одним из недостатков этого способа является то, что вам придется создавать файл `package.json` вручную (если только кто-то не знает способ автоматизировать это с помощью `grunt` или чего-то еще).

Comment: А в какой файл это вписать:
-projectName
--node_modules
--myproject1
---sub-project
--myproject2

Comment: @Danoslo255 это ваши проекты myproject1, myproject2 и папка `node_modules` на уровень выше